# Passing filter attributes to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, redux

I three components.

1. Parent
2. List item
3. Filter component

The parent gets it's data via redux state:

#### Parent

```
const mappedEvents =
  events.length === 0 ? (
    <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Det finns inte några händelser</p>
  ) : (
    events.reverse().map((event, i) => {
      var driver = event.driver ? keyedDrivers[event.driver] : false
      var carrier = driver ? keyedCarriers[driver.carrier] : false
      var customer = event.customer ? keyedCustomers[event.customer] : false

      return (
        <div>
          <EventItem // This is a list item
            key={i}
            event={event}
            customer={customer}
            carrier={carrier}
            driver={driver}
            lock={keyedLocks[event.unit] || { address: {} }}
          />
        </div>
      )
    })
  )
```

Then inside of `return` I display it like:

`<Grid>{mappedEvents}</Grid>`
This gives me a list,

but I'd like to be able to filter it. So I created a filter component which also gets it's data via redux state.

#### Filter Component

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      filteredEvents: ''
    }
  }

  toggle(event) {
    this.setState({ filteredEvents: event.target.value })
  }
  ...

const organizationList = carriers
  .filter(
    carrier =>
      !this.state.filteredEvents ||
      carrier.organization.indexOf(this.state.filteredEvents) >= 0
  )
  .map(carrier => (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value={carrier.organization}
        onChange={this.toggle.bind(this)}
      />
      <MenuItem eventKey={carrier.id} key={carrier.id}>
        {carrier.organization}
      </MenuItem>
    </div>
  ))
```

This renders a list of things an user can check:

However when I click on one of the checkboxes it start to filter the array of checkboxes:

So I wonder how I can pass the filter component so I can start filtering the `EventItem` array. Should I start making a reducer that makes the filtering or should the filter component calls callbacks back to parent, and parent renders the filtered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to keep your filter state in the redux store. Your  filters should dispatch an action that updates the state, and then when you render the list you would filter it there.

```
events.filter((event) => {
  // filter based on redux state
}).reverse().map((event, i) => {
```

--

```
toggle(event) {
  // this.setState({ filteredEvents: event.target.value })
  // dispatch an action that updates the redux state filters here
}
```

---

**A little more info**

I would probably store the filters as booleans. Reducer initial state would look something like this (or you could have separate reducers for events/filters):

```
events: [],
filters: {
  qlocx: false,
  best: false,
  bring: false // etc..
}
```

The update filter action would set the filter boolean corresponding to the checkbox.

In your `mapStateToProps` you would have both `events` and `filters`

Then in your render function you can use `.filter` to filter the events based on your filter state.

You could use something like reselect to cache the filtered list, but with a small list you shouldn't see any performance problems from a single filter function.

```
// inside the render function, filter the array based on filters set
// just a simple render function example for demonstration
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {events
        .filter((event) => {
          // filter based on redux state
          if (event.qlocx && filters.qlocx) {
            return true;
          }
          // etc..

          // filter any that don't match (might want to return true if no filters are set)
          return false;
        })
        .reverse()
        .map((event, i) => {
```

---

**Demo**

Here's a small demo, but no redux. It's using setState as a replacement for dispatched actions and passing state down as props instead of using `mapStateToProps`:

```js
class Filters extends React.Component {
  onUpdateFilter = (event) => {
    // event.target is the input that you changed, so you can get the name and checked properties
    this.props.updateFilters(event.target.name, event.target.checked);
  }
  
  render() {
    const {
      filters
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="one" onChange={this.onUpdateFilter} value={filters.one} />
        <input type="checkbox" name="two" onChange={this.onUpdateFilter} value={filters.two} />
        <input type="checkbox" name="three" onChange={this.onUpdateFilter} value={filters.three} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class List extends React.Component {
  // this would be your reducer's `initialState`
  state = {
    filters: {}
  };
  
  // this code would be in your reducer, and you'd just dispatch an action here
  updateFilters = (name, value) => {
    this.setState({
      filters: {
        // this just makes a copy of state.filters and sets state.filters[name] = value
        ...this.state.filters,
        [name]: value
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    // both filters and items would come from mapStateToProps
    const {filters} = this.state;
    const {items} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <pre>filters = {JSON.stringify(filters)}</pre>
        <Filters
          filters={filters}
          updateFilters={this.updateFilters}
        />
        <ul>
          {this.props.items
            .filter((item) => {
              if (filters.one && !item.one) {
                return false;
              }
              if (filters.two && !item.two) {
                return false;
              }
              if (filters.three && !item.three) {
                return false;
              }
              
              return true;
            })
            .map((item) => (
              <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// this list would come from your reducer via mapStateToProps
const listItems = [
  {name: 'Item 1', one: true},
  {name: 'Another item 1', one: true},
  {name: 'Item 2', two: true},
  {name: 'Item 2,1', one: true, two: true},
  {name: 'Item 2,3', two: true, three: true},
  {name: 'Item 3', three: true}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <List items={listItems} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. First I want to say that I started laughing when I saw your profile pic (don't know why). I guess the reducer should do the filtering? And then I will return my filter to the parent component via `mapStateToProps`? Sorry, but I have a hard time picturing this, I'm just really stuck.

Comment: it's a funny picture :) -- I added some more info to the post, let me know if you have other questions

Comment: So every time I want to filter on something else I need to add that attribute in my `initialState`? And how can I them change from `false` to `true`? Should `filter component` access those values via redux store and when selecting a checkbox the value should turn from `false` to `true`? Everything still feels blurry Austin. I don't blame you, I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Added a little demo that might help, some things are different because there's no redux but it should give a good starting place.

Comment: Thanks you very much for that snippet. I wonder if there's some way I could have a discussion with you about this? I will accept your answer because of the snippet you provided. I have not yet solved my problem, which sucks he he.